# crud operation without using serializers

Tags: json, django, rest, crud

This is the error:
In line 7 and line 9;

**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

This is my code:

```
import requests
BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
ENDPOINT = 'api/'
def get_resource(id):
    resp = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}{ENDPOINT}{id}/")
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.json())
id = input("enter some id:")
get_resource(id)
```

Comment: check `resp`'s `Content-type` reponse header. It should `application/json`.

Comment: yeah I've mentioned content-type in response.

Answer (score 0):

Response returns a big data from this site with headers, status code and other...
You should to dump also content of this response. [Read there](https://realpython.com/python-requests/)

Try next:

```
resp.text.json()
```

Or:

```
resp.content.json()
```

**content** gives you access to the raw bytes of the response payload, you will often want to convert them into a string using a character encoding such as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

This is my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from withoutrest.models import employee
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.core.serializers import serialize


class EmployeeDetails(View):
    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        emp = employee.objects.get(id=id)
        json_data = serialize('json', [emp,])
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```